# Is IRS Form 8938 asking me to double-count foreign assets?

Tags: united-states, fbar

[FBAR](http://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Report-of-Foreign-Bank-and-Financial-Accounts-FBAR) and [Form 8938](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i8938/index.html) require the reporting of the maximum balance/value of a foreign account during a tax year.

If, say, I sell $100,000 worth of stock from my (foreign) securities account and desposit the proceeds to my (foreign) checking account, then it seems I would have to list this $100,000 value twice.  Isn’t that double counting?  The overall totals, particularly Form 8938 Part I Line 2, would give a false picture of my total financial assets, and perhaps make the interest and dividends I report look understated.

Am I truly supposed to list each account where this identical batch of money was held?

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you effectively need to "double count" when shifting balances between foreign accounts.

Answer (score -1):

The requirement is to report the highest balance on the account, it has nothing to do with your income.

Comment: OP did not mention income at all.

Comment: @Eric so what's this: "*and perhaps make the interest and dividends I report look understated*"?